# If someone doesn't believe in eternal and uncreated quran is he an apostat?

Tags: quran

If someone doesn't believe in eternal and uncreated quran is he an apostat or did he committed apostasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predecessors unanimously agreed that whoever says that the Qur’an is created has become an infidel (kafir كافر).

So you must be careful.

"قال شيخ الإسلام ابن تيمية حاكياً عن السلف: ولهذا كفروا من يقول إن القرآن مخلوق وإن الله لا يرى في الآخرة. انتهى من مجموع الفتاوى."

Sheikh Al-Islam Ibn Taymiyyah said, narrating from the predecessors: That is why they disbelieve those who say that the Qur’an is created and that God is not seen in the Hereafter.

Comment: Should be "God is not seen in the Hereafter"

Comment: But nowhere in the quran it is mentioned that quran is eternal and uncreated. So if one says quran is non eternal and created he still is following the quran and 6 pillars of faith